# Display HTTP response on a webpage using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, api, clickatell

I'm developing an SMS application using the clickatell API,

I want to show the credit balance on my page.

The http request to show the credit balance is:

http://api.clickatell.com/http/getbalance?api_id=xxx&user=xxx&password=xxx

This page returns "Credit: 158.500"

Is it possible to display this on my application/webpage using PHP?

I've looked all over and am clueless,

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: `I've looked all over and am clueless` Now I don't believe that for one second...

Comment: `curl` or `file_get_contents` is what you're looking for.

Comment: it's hard being a noob! sometimes you don't what to search for! thanks dragoste, i'll look into those

Comment: <?php echo file_get_contents("http://api.clickatell.com/http/getbalance?api_id=xxx&user=xxx&password=xxx"); ?> : That's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 $credit = file_get_contents('http://api.clickatell.com/http/getbalance?api_id=xxx&user=xxx&password=xxx');
```

PHP's `file_get_contents` function will retrieve the remote data. You can then `echo` the contents of `$credit` variable anywhere in your page.